# override maven mirror settings on a build server

Tags: maven, build

we have a settings.xml on a build server that restricts access to outside repositories and forces access to a local repository.

with the cooperation of the policy makers behind this, we are investigating the possibility to selectively (from a project's pom.xml) enable outside repository access.

is this possible?  if so, would it be as simple as configuring the repository in the pom.xml?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid it isn't possible. You need to specify an alternative settings.xml on the command line.

Comment: ah-ha!  that might work since each project is configured separately in the build server.  thanks!